# 2 phase commit using Spring jdbctemplate on different database

Tags: spring, jdbctemplate, 2phase-commit

I have following requirement and need to know how can I implement the 2 phase commit using Spring JDBCtemplate.

1. The Application (JAR) will run standalone as schedule JOB.(No Web Container)
2. I need to connect 2 database. (Database 1 and Database 2)
3. Connect Database 1 (Oracle) (select the DATA) and store in variable.
4. Connect Database 2 (postgresql) (update/insert the DATA collected from the database 1 to database 2).
5. If the transaction is successful for Database 2 then
6. Connect The Database one and update the FLAG in the particular table.

Kindly suggest me with the sample working code or suggest alternate quick approach.

Regards,
Mithil Shukla.